# How can I center(horizontal and vertical) cards on the enire page, which will work also on mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

On big screens like Monitors it works perfectly as it should, but on small screens like Mobile phones some cards will be cut off.

On bigger screens the cards will be shown in one row and if the screen gets smaller the cards will adapt and go onto new line:

[image: bigger]
[image: smaller]

On smaller screens instead the cards are one below the other like it should be, but some cards i cant reach and where cut off like you can see in the picture below:

[image: problem]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="height=device-height width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery_ui.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Übersicht</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-content-center align-items-center vw-100 vh-100">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">1</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">2</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">3</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">4</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">5</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">6</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">7</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-header text-center">8</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                    <div class="card-text">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div style="display: grid; place-items: center;" class="vw-100 vh-100">
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-content-center align-items-center">
This was the solution I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from your first div the class vh-100. 
Or use it for the screens you need like vh-md-100, vh-lg-100, vh-xl-100.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-content-center align-items-center vw-100 vh-md-100 vh-lg-100 vh-xl-100">
```

Live [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/khLbcusm/2/)

Comment: @x0tester0x My example works like your code. just for sm screens i don't use vh-100